# How often should I request authorization to access Google APIs?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, authorization

My GAE applications works with Google's Fusion Tables thru Google API. Currently I request authorization each time I should add some data to Fusion Tables:

```
class TestHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        credentials = AppAssertionCredentials(scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fusiontables')
        http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http(memcache))
        service = build('fusiontables', 'v1', http=http)
        # addition of the data happens here
```

But do I really need to do it? Probably I should store authorization data (`http`?) somewhere? Like memcache? And then re-use it? Then how long the auth data is valid for? Or, is it already done by [Google APIs Client Library for Python](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/) I use?

Comment: yeah I'd like to know this too. maybe you only need to build() for every request? or maybe you need to do everything?